# Customizing bubbles position with d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a bubble chart with two types of nodes , Ip and User , indicated as blue and pink , but here i have the data where I have a visualization where both the nodes are mixed as in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IUU6.jpg

But I want to layer it with different colors https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZrNH.jpg

Here is my working code

```
var nodes = [some dummy data here]

var width = 1000
var height = 600

//Defining colors
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["user", "IP"])
    .range(["#5688F0", "#ff6074"]);

const forceX = d3.forceX(width / 2).strength(0.015)
const forceY = d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(0.015)

var force = d3.forceSimulation()
    .velocityDecay(0.2)
    .force("x", forceX)
    .force("y", forceY)
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(function (d) {
        return (d.edge_count * 0.0055 + 3);
    }).iterations(5))
    .nodes(nodes).on("tick", ticked);

//Defining the svg
var svg = d3.select(".cichart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

//Creating circles

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", function (d) { return d.edge_count * 0.0055 })
    .style("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i % 3); })

circles.on("mouseover", function (n) {
    circles.style("stroke", function (d) {
        if (d.id == n.id)
            return "black";
        else
            return "white";
    })
    circles.style("stroke-width", function (d) {
        if (d.id == n.id)
            return 2;
        else
            return 0;
    })
    labelbox(n)
})

function labelbox(d) {
    var view = d3.select('#abc')
    view.html(`<div>Label :${d.node_label}</div> <div>Number of connections :${d.edge_count}</div>  `)
}

function ticked(e) {
    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a "position" in the forceX and forceY, so doing something like:

```
const forceX = d3.forceX(function(d) {
  const position = d.group === "user" ? -100 : 100;
  return position;
}).strength(0.15)
```

Will set the node position depending on the group.

On the other hand, you are not setting the node color based on the group (maybe I am missing something), but I would do it as follows:

```
.style("fill", function (d, i) {
  return color(d.group);
});
```

Here is an Observable notebook with the working code:

[Link](https://observablehq.com/@garciaguillermoa/force-directed-graph-with-colored-node-borders/2)

Comment: i want it to come as in circle as shown here https://imgur.com/a/BRAxlUj